# How to write String.Contains in Theamleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing my if condition like this but getting error. This the code I am writing.

```
<th:block th:if="${#strings.contains(#obj.getTitle(), 'choice')} and ${#strings.contains(#obj.getProductTitle(), 'honey')}"></th:block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the strings.contains expression, the actual problem is in:

```
#obj.getTitle()
```

If you have a standard getter method the correct expression is:

```
${#strings.contains(obj.getTitle(), 'choice')} and ${#strings.contains(obj.getProductTitle(), 'honey')}
```

or it can just be...

```
${#strings.contains(obj.Title, 'choice')} and ${#strings.contains(obj.ProductTitle, 'honey')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write it this way (without # before variables in spring expression):

```
<th:block th:if="${#strings.contains(obj.getTitle(), 'choice')} and ${#strings.contains(obj.getProductTitle(), 'honey')}"></th:block>
```